# Combinational loops in HDLs

Tags: vhdl, verilog

This is just an experiment I'm trying to wrap my brain around.

So I've got two registers r1 r2 and two wires w1 w2.  What I want is, if both r's are 1, both w's should be 1.  If one r is 1, the corresponding w should be 1 and the other should be 0.  If both r's are 0, w1 should be 1 and w2 should be 0.

11=>11

10=>10

01=>01

00=>10

The caveat is I want the assign for w1 not to include r2 directly, and vice versa.  So, I've got (in Verilog for instance--a VHDL answer would be perfectly fine too)

```
assign w1 = r1 | !w2;
assign w2 = r2 | !w1;
```

Which is necessary but not sufficient.  All the cases above are true, but 00=>01 is also true.  In fact when r1=r2=0, it just creates a cycle of wires without a driver, so I think the result is non-deterministic.

Is there any way to get the result I'm looking for without including r2 in the assignment for w1, or vice versa?  (And without introducing new variables).  Basically just to ensure that in a wire-cycle, w1 is pulled high and w2 pulled low?

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to include R2 in the formula for W1, when it clearly is a function of R2? I can't think of any good reason for this.

Comment: @Tim Long answer: I'm trying to write a sudoku solver based purely on a feedback loop.  The registers represent the initial puzzle values, the wires form a feedback loop that eliminate potential values from unsolved cells.  Simplify to a 2x1 sudoku: we know solved1=r1|!possible2, and possible2=r2|!solved1, same as above.  I've got a solution that works iteratively, eliminating "possible" wire and just doing something like `r1<=r1|!r2` at each clock tick, but I was looking for a way to use a feedback loop so I could do it without a clock, but it looks like that's exactly what's not possible.

Comment: Obviously the full sudoku problem has lots more variables and lots more interdependencies, so following them all back to their origin and inlining them, I don't even know if that's possible.  Hence the inability to include the registers in the formulas for the wires.

Comment: Yes, a full sudoku solver would be quite elaborate, but I don't see that you're going to get there with just wires like this (and it would never work in silicon/fpga if that's your end goal). If you  have a feedback loop without a clock, then you can't really guarantee the state of any wire at any time. Different wires in your circuit would run at different speeds, it would be nearly impossible to organize anything at a high level. Maybe can you change 'w' to a register, and then clock it for several iterations to iterate through your feedback until it reaches equilibrium?

Comment: @Tim, Here's the [feedback loop approach](https://gist.github.com/2961152), which sometimes works, but sometimes doesn't (even on the same puzzle), i.e. there's some non-determinism from the feedback loop, which wap26 already established.  Here's the [iterative approach](https://gist.github.com/2884473), which works always (assuming the puzzle is solvable by simple elimination), usually in 6-7 ticks.  A third approach using only wires I guess would be to have the outputs of one iteration feed into a 2nd iteration and so on, but then we'd have to fix the number of iterations; 10 may be enough.

Comment: And by "works", I mean I synthesized it to a test board, fed in data via serial, ran it, and read back the output via serial (that's the "read" and "write" states in the code), and got the correct result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, I think there is no clean way to do this without extra wires/signals and without your cross dependency.

By the way, your "cyclical wires" are commonly referred to as a **combinational loops** and it is a good practice to avoid these.

1. As for the simulation of a VHDL model with combinational loop, the result is deterministic provided the simulator converges to a stable point, ie no more signal value change. If signal values continuously change, then you are likely to reach your simulator's iteration limit. I don't know for Verilog but I assume it is deterministic as well.
2. As for synthesis, tools with either reject this construct and raise an error, or try to handle this, with a possible very bad impact on timing.

Again, even if your simulation is ok and your synthesis tool allows this, combinational loops should be avoided.

Comment: Another common name is **combinatorial loops**. Regardless, they're not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

What you have currently is very similar to an SR latch, and as such it has a metastable condition (also known as a race condition).

From your truth table above though, it looks like w2 should be set only to r2.
`assign w2 = r2;`

That change should fix your race condition; though as expressed above, be wary of the large restrictions created by combinational logic.